# Can you prove IFF statements only one way with a implication and a negation?

Tags: logic

Let's say we want to prove A is true if and only if B is true. I start out by assuming A is true and prove B is true. Then I prove that if A is not true then B is not true. Does this complete the proof? In other words by proving that if A is not true then B is not true do I no longer have to prove that A is true if B is true?

Comment: Yes. Showing that $B$ implies $A$ is the same as showing **not** $A$ implies **not** $B$.